# Error trying to make a circular UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, cornerradius

I have an UIImageView in my screen layout which dynamically resizes according to the container view dimensions. I would like to transform it in a circular view and I'm using the following code:

```
let dSize: CGFloat = min(imageview.frame.height, imageview.frame.width)
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dSize, dSize)
imageview.clipsToBounds = true
imageview.layer.cornerRadius = dSize/2.0
imageview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

The problem is that the resulting view is not always circular. To achieve the effect I have to divide `dSize` by *2.0* on iPhone 4, by *1.7* on iPhone 5/5s and by *1.5* on iPhone 6/6s. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you add any constraints to the `imageview`?

Comment: is it in viewDidLoad func?

Comment: Is your view always a square? Because if width != height, then it will not be a circle, it will be more like a rounded rect

Comment: I have added an aspect ratio 1:1 constraint which theoretically makes it always square (which I know is a required condition to achieve the circular shape)

Comment: yes, it's in viewDidLoad

Comment: viewDidLoad is too early for geometry, try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @Drmorgan: great! that did the trick. The problem now is that I can see for a spit second the uiimageview as a square and then becoming a circle. Any other method I can try?

Comment: sorry for the mess with the comments.The problem is still there

Comment: @Drmorgan: I'm trying everything but I still can see the view transforming in a circle instead of being directly presented in the new shape

Comment: @skyddict: yes the view is always a square, the first two lines of code assure that.

Comment: @Claus Post your constraints or storyboard(as screenshot) here

Comment: I'm loading a square image, the uiimageview is set on Aspect Fill and I have set an aspect ration 1:1. The only thing I'm noticing is that the view is not square when arrives to the addCircleBorderToImageView function

(lldb) po imgView.frame
(0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this

```
//To make your imageView circular
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height/2;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

//To add border
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

Comment: Hi. Please check the comments. Placing the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews solves the problem but I can see the view transforming in a circle.

Comment: I am doing this in viewDidLoad and got no problem so far.

Comment: Can you replace your piece of code with mine in your viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: @Claus: Make a `CATransaction` around it and disable animation. First: `CATransaction.begin()` then `CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)` then your code then `CATransaction.commit()`. (Can't do newlines in comments.)

Comment: I don't get a perfect circle. I achieve the effect only using the approach in my question

Comment: @Jesper: tried it, nothing. I'm still in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: What is your view mode for imageView? It should be Aspect Fill

Comment: I'm checking in the debugger the method get called twice the first time has dimension (240,124) the second time is a square (151,151) I guess because the layout constraints kick in

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad()` is too early for geometry on your `UIImageView` instead, try `viewWillAppear()` as this is where you are guaranteed geometry to be available.

Since you are using auto layout I recommend sticking it into `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. This gets called everytime auto layout occurs. This can be multiple times even if the view doesn't change orientation. As you noted in the comments, make sure to call `super` inside the method (you should do the same for view controller lifecycle methods like `viewDidLoad()` etc. as well)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.addCircleBorderToImageView(self.imageView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.addCircleBorderToImageView(self.imageView)
}

// I made this UIView so it can be used with any view not just image views.
func addCircleBorderToImageView(imgView: UIView) {
    let dSize: CGFloat = min(imgView.frame.height, imgView.frame.width)
    imgView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, dSize, dSize) // centered in container you want to use bounds over frame for this scenario
    imgView.clipsToBounds = true
    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = dSize/2.0
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your full answer. The result is the same unfortunately: I keep on seeing the view as square for half a second then it becomes a circle. I also tried to add the CATransaction code proposed by @Jesper, but nothing.

Comment: I'm loading a square image, the uiimageview is set on Aspect Fill and I have set an aspect ration 1:1. The only thing I'm noticing is that the view is not square when arrives to the addCircleBorderToImageView function
LOG
 (lldb) po imgView.frame (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)

Comment: what are your constraints?  I have a demo project working, for the image view I pined to the left margin, pined to top layout guide, and set height/width to 50 each.  I would recommend adding some auto layout rules to keep width/height the same

Comment: The view is centred with the container on X and Y. Equal height to the container and aspect ratio 1:1 to keep it like a square

Comment: I updated my demo project to have centered in container x and y, height = 50 and aspect ratio 1:1 and I have no issues.  Just made an edit to my answer it should be `bounds` not `frame` as `frame` with change it's position origin to `(0,0)`  If you would like the demo project to compare please private message me.